# UILocalNotification always setting the date to local timezone

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a method that makes the store of a UILocalNotification:

```
- (void)save:(NSString *)program at:(NSDate*)date  {

    NSLog(@"date to save: %@", date);
   // NSLog(@"timezone: %@",[date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]);


    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"date to fire: %@", date);
    localNotification.fireDate = date;

    NSString *s=[program stringByAppendingString:@" is now on "];
    NSString *title=[s stringByAppendingString:channel];
    localNotification.alertBody = title;

    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show...";
    //localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];


    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    NSLog(@"notification to save %@",localNotification);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    // Dismiss the view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And I have as output:

```
date to save: 2013-08-29 17:00:00 +0000
date to fire: 2013-08-29 17:00:00 +0000
notification to save <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0xc0c4240>{fire date = Thursday, August 29, 2013, 6:00:00 PM Central European Standard Time, time zone = (null), repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Thursday, August 29, 2013, 6:00:00 PM Central European Standard Time, user info = (null)}
```

Despite uncommenting the timezone setting, the UILocalNotification is always incrementing by one hour, why, and how ?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The date you pass in in GMT, which in you case is does not match your local time zone.

So when you set the date to 17:00 your time corrects it to you timezone (CET) which is GMT+1.
Thus an hour gets added to you date.

A solution is to set the [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) timezone to GMT:

```
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName@"GMT"];
```

[From the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW1):

> The date specified in fireDate is interpreted according to the value
>   of this property. If you specify nil (the default), the fire date is
>   interpreted as an absolute GMT time, which is suitable for cases such
>   as countdown timers. If you assign a valid NSTimeZone object to this
>   property, the fire date is interpreted as a wall-clock time that is
>   automatically adjusted when there are changes in time zones; an
>   example suitable for this case is an an alarm clock.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in that case, all the notifications will be setted to GMT. I mean that if someone is in GMT+5, he'll have the notification at GMT, no ?

Comment: No, iOS will use your date and time correct to the user timezone. See my edit.

Comment: You're assigning a valid NSTimeZone to UILocalNotification(GMT) in this case, thus, all notifications will be on GMT, even that the person is not in GMT. My idea is why not assigning `localTimeZone` to the passed value and assign `localTimeZone` too to the UILocalNotification object?

Comment: Yes that can also be, but it will be more work to build. My solution will also work. Since the, as stated by the documentation, the date is seen an wall-clock time and changed to active timezone.  But yes you take the date apart with `NSDateComponents` and calculate the offset.

Comment: Yes, your solution is working, I tested it, but i just wonder if it'll work for ALL time zones. And you answered me that it'll work ;D. Accepted :). Thank you very much.